# Why when publish message to RabbitMQ with MassTransit, sends to another endpoint with skipped?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, rabbitmq, masstransit

Here comes my code on my publisher app (a netcore API).

```
services.AddMassTransit(masstransit =>
        {
            masstransit.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
            {
                cfg.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://srv-docker-dev-01"), "/", h =>
                {
                    h.Username("guest");
                    h.Password("guest");
                });

                cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("implantacao", e =>
                {
                    e.ConfigureConsumeTopology = false;
                    e.Bind<ClienteAlteradoEvento>();
                });
            });
        });
```

Even before I create a consumer, my RabbitMQ shows a skipped queue.
[image]

[image]

And the message is delivered on this __skipped.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Just a few points:

- My consumer will not have access to the event class of my producer.
- I will have 2 queues which have to consume my API. I'll probably configure another receive endpoint.
- I thought I should have only 1 exchange for each microservice. Like, all the events published by comercial microservice, should use the same exchange, but MassTransit is creating one exchange each type. Is that correct?

Any thoughs and ideas, will be welcome. I'm just learning about RabbitMQ.

EDIT

Microservice A: Have endpoints to receive user input data of customers. Users send data like names, contracts, and anything else (many different types of data can be changed on different endpoints). Every time a customer is updated, this API should publish messages to update other microservices too. Lets say we have at least 3 different events: CustomerDataUpdatedEvent, CustomerAddressUpdatedEvent, CustomerContractsUpdatedEvent.

Microservice B: Want to consume the updates from costumer published by Microservice A. We don't have access to CustomerDataUpdatedEvent, CustomerAddressUpdatedEvent, CustomerContractsUpdatedEvent classes. We should build our class type on its side.

Microservice C: Want to consume the updates from costumer published by Microservice A. We don't have access to CustomerDataUpdatedEvent, CustomerAddressUpdatedEvent, CustomerContractsUpdatedEvent classes. We should build our class type on its side.

Neither B or C have access to class type on microservice A.

Is that possible? Does it makes sense?

Thanks

Comment: As long as the namespace + type name are the same, the message should be consumed. You can literally cut-n-paste the file between projects if you don't want to share a package reference.

Comment: I got this on the easy way. It's working, again, thanks for being nice. But just to know, a more advanced discussion maybe (or I'm just making confusion), there is no way to configure MassTransit to recognize different types as published/received the message? Like a config where I can tell type X on the producer is type Y on the receiver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are configuring a receive endpoint without any consumers on it. So any message produced that arrives on the queue will just be copied to the `_skipped` queue.

I'd suggest [reading some documentation](https://masstransit.io/documentation/concepts/messages) to get the feel for how messages, consumers, and endpoints are configured.

I wouldn't suggest using a single exchange (or even a single queue) for all the messages in a service, but since you're just learning I don't really know what else to suggest without details.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @chris-patterson. No one better than you to tell us how to make it works :D
Every single sample and video I got about Mass Transit shows me scenarios where my Consumer .Net Project can reference assemblies from my Producer assembly. This is the main point I want to solve. Make consumers read from a queue without the exactly same type between them. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

It is not recommended by Chris Patterson [here](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/discussions), you could use RabbitMQ.Client. but it is not impossible.
In this [documentation](https://masstransit.io/documentation/transports/rabbitmq#send) there are two ways to better understand:

- Using ISendEndpoint `Send<T>(...)`

  ```
       var endpoint = await busControl.GetSendEndpoint(new Uri("exchange:my-exchange"));
       await endpoint.Send(new {});
  ```
- Using IBus `Publish<T>(...)`

  ```
       var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq((cfgBus) =>
       {
           cfgBus.Host(host: eventbusoptions.Host);

           // Remove default wrapper message
           cfgBus.ClearSerialization();
           cfgBus.UseRawJsonSerializer();

           // Set exchange name
           cfgBus.Message<SubmitOrder>(top =>
           {
               top.SetEntityName(eventbusoptions.ExchangeName);
           });

           // Configurations per Publish
           cfgBus.Publish<SubmitOrder>(top =>
           {
               top.ExchangeType = eventbusoptions.ExchangeType;
               top.Durable = false;

               top.BindQueue(eventbusoptions.ExchangeName, eventbusoptions.QueueName, bind =>
               {
                   bind.RoutingKey = eventbusoptions.RoutingKey;
                   bind.ExchangeType = eventbusoptions.ExchangeType;
                   bind.Durable = false;
               });
           });
       });

       await _bus.Publish<SubmitOrder>(order, context => context.SetRoutingKey(_eventBusOptions.RoutingKey));
  ```

Comment: There is a sample https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-Direct

Answer (score 0):

I just realize MassTransit isn't what I'm looking for right now.
I read about RabbitMQ and people told me MassTransit should be a nice approach but I disagree. Maybe for some scenarios it would be perfect, but when you can't have the same type on both projects, it's a pain.
The "exchanges must be type" isn't flexible enough.

The problem of my question is the answer gave by Chris. But Mass will not do what I want. His answer is right, btw.